# Definition of textbook RSA

Tags: rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis, terminology

What is the definition of textbook or "raw" RSA?

What are some of the properties of textbook RSA?

How does it differ from other schemes based on RSA?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Textbook RSA**:

Choose two large primes $p$ and $q$.
Let $n=p\cdot q$. Choose $e$ such that $gcd(e,\varphi(n))=1$ (where $\varphi(n)=(p-1)\cdot (q-1)$). Find $d$ such that $e\cdot d\equiv 1\bmod{\varphi(n)}$. In other words, $d$ is the modular inverse of $e$, ($d\equiv e^{-1}\bmod{\varphi(n)}$).

$(e, n)$ is the public key, $(d, n)$ the private one.

- To encrypt a message $m$, compute $c\equiv m^e\mod n$.
- To decrypt a ciphertext $c$, compute $m \equiv c^d\mod n$.

Signing and verifying messages is also defined (omitted for brevity).

**Some (Undesirable) Properties of Textbook RSA**:

1. It is malleable. I.e., if you give me a ciphertext $c$ which encrypts $m$, I can compute $c'\equiv c\cdot 2^e\mod n$. When the owner of the private key decrypts $c'$, she will get $2m\mod n$. In other words, I can make predictable changes to ciphertexts.
2. It is deterministic, and thus not [semantically secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security). I.e., I can distinguish between the encryptions of $0$ and $1$ (simply by encrypting both values myself and comparing the ciphertexts).

**Differences with Deployed RSA**:

1. [Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#Padding_schemes)
2. [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) is sometimes used in deployed systems for more efficient decryption.
3. $e$ is often statically set to $65537 = 2^{16} + 1$ for encryption speed (since there are only two set bits in that number).
4. Side-channel attack mitigations can be put in place for deployed systems too.

In no way is my list comprehensive, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Some textbooks, and actual implementations, use $e\cdot d\equiv 1\pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)}$, which covers _all_ working $d$, rather than _some_ working $d$.

Comment: Also it leaks the jacobi symbole of the message. You can know if your medsage is a quadratic residue

Comment: For completeness, you might also want to note that [textbook RSA is insecure for short messages.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/in-textbook-rsa-with-low-public-exponent-how-big-does-a-random-message-needs-to) In particular, there's an obvious attack whenever $m^e < n$ (just take the non-modular $e$-th root), but there are other attacks that apply even when $e$ is large but $m$ is small.

Comment: @David天宇Wong Can you explain (or give a reference) the Jacobi symbol leakage?

Comment: I've tried to get a list of attacks that are possible on textbook RSA [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/which-attacks-are-possible-against-raw-textbook-rsa). That kind-of failed as there were a lot more than expected. As indicated correctly in this answer "In no way is my list comprehensive"... And neither should it be, it is a separate topic - if not more - on its own.

Comment: Would the group (e.g. $\mathbf{Z}_N^{*}$) be considered part of the textbook definition?

Comment: This answer currently uses slightly incorrect notation. For example, in "compute $c\equiv m^e\mod n$", that should be $c=m^e\bmod n$, or $c:=m^e\bmod n$ or  $c\gets m^e\bmod n$, for fear that it's understood "compute _some_ $c$ with $c\equiv m^e\pmod n$", as occurred in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/107837/555). Also the bound $0\le m<n$ is untold, and that could lead to the different issue in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/107760/555). Also, $p\ne q$ is required for decryption to work for all $m$, and for $\varphi(n)=(p-1)\cdot(q-1)$ to hold.

Answer (score 16):

RSA is both an encryption and signature function. I have heard the term "textbook RSA" used mostly with the encryption function, but the same basic principle applies to RSA signatures as well. It is essentially RSA without any padding.

There is no canonical definition of textbook RSA (e.g., does it include restrictions on choosing safe primes or not?) and so it may differ by context, but it is what is called "plain RSA" on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29). Since Wikipedia evolves, also see [these slides](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/courses/cs255_winter07/rsa.ppt) from Dan Boneh.

Textbook RSA has no semantic security, therefore it is not secure against chosen plaintext attacks or ciphertext attacks. This is because, respectively, it is deterministic (encrypting the same message twice produces the same ciphertext) and multiplicatively homomorphic (an encrypted values can be multiplicatively modified under encryption).

The main alternative to textbook RSA encryption is RSA with [OAEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_Asymmetric_Encryption_Padding). This variant is semantically, CPA-, and CCA-secure. RSA+OAEP is randomized and has no homomorphisms. OAEP itself is a second generation padding scheme, the first generation only providing semantic/CPA-security for RSA.

RSA signatures can also be padded. RSA with PSS makes the signatures randomized.

Comment: The acronyms were thrown at my face too violently, but great answer overall.

Answer (score 3):

A) **RSA**

RSA is an asymmetric encryption method. RSA is one of the Public Key Cryptography methods. This method makes use of two keys: a public key, known to all, for encryption and a private key, kept secret, for decryption.

Operations in RSA:
The RSA algorithm involves three steps:

1. key generation - Key pairs are generated: a private key and a public key.
2. Encryption - by using the public key the message is encrypted.
3. Decryption - by using the private keys the message is decrypted.

B) **Textbook RSA**

Some points regarding textbook RSA is given below:

1. Textbook RSA is insecure
2. Textbook RSA encryption:

• public key: $(N,e)$ Encrypt: $C = M^e \pmod N$

• private key: $d$ Decrypt:   $C^d = M \pmod N$

```
                           (M Î ZN)
```

3. Completely insecure cryptosystem:

   • Does not satisfy basic definitions of security.
   • Many attacks exist.
4. The RSA trapdoor permutation is not a cryptosystem.
5. A simple attack on textbook RSA

[image]

- Session-key $K$ is $64$ bits. View $K\in\{0,\ldots,2^{64}-1\}$

  Eavesdropper sees: $C = K^e \pmod N$ .
- Suppose $K = K1\cdot K2$ where $K1, K2 < 234$ . (prob. 20%)

  Then: $C/K1^e = K2^e \pmod N$
- Build table: $C/1^e, C/2^e, C/3^e, \ldots, C/2^{34e} . time: $2^34$

  For K2 = 0,…, 2^34 test if $K2^e$ is in the table. time: $2^{34} 34$
- Attack time: $2^{40} \ll 2^{64}$

6. Never use textbook RSA because of less security.

Comment: Hi Anu, and thanks for your answer. Currently it is pretty hard to read. Maybe you could take a look at [our supported MathJax formatting](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/1172). Instead of A / B you could use sections. For numbered lists, please use the MarkDown list feature. I'm certainly not sure what "(M Î ZN)" is, but it certainly should not be using the code formatting feature.

Comment: Hi Maarten, thanks for your support, I will use the applications you mentioned.

Comment: This answer is taken from Dan Boneh and a credit is due.

Comment: I would add to Operations: signature and signature verification