# possibility to encrypt data using AES and RSA frequently?

Tags: rsa, aes, multiple-encryption

I am doing a research for encrypting data, I found many research doing multiple encryption using DES and RSA ? but in symmetric cryptography the best algorithm is AES so I need to do multiple cryptography for data using both algorithms ? Is there any rules to follow this way specially in the key length ? any recommendation ?
Thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, nowadays DES is not really secure anymore.

Yes, for usual applications, AES properties allow it to be be used as drop-in (as long as the different block and key size is kept in mind).

RSA has a maximum data length, but for usual RSA key sizes and padding modes (eg. 4096 OAEP), encrypting AES keys is always possible. See [What is the maximum size of the plaintext message for RSA OAEP?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-the-plaintext-message-for-rsa-oaep) for more details how to calculate the maximum length.