# RSA2048 smallest possible modulus

Tags: rsa

what is the smallest possible modulus for RSA2048? I generate a random data with I want to encrypt by a textbook RSA2048 and I'm not sure where the first 1-bit should be.

According to OpenSSL source code and used padding function, the first byte seems to be 0, 2 follows and than there could be anything. Seems I need first 14bits to be 0 to ensure my plaintext fits the RSA modulus.

Comment: what you mean by smallest module? See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-the-plaintext-message-for-rsa-oaep):

Comment: c^e mod m. The m is module/modulus?

Comment: What is the reason other than curiosity? do you need to find $n=pq$ where two $p$ and $q$ are two primes such that $n$ is the smallest possible 2048-bit integer?

Comment: No, the RSA2048 key is just a common OpenSSL generated key. I need to generate c that way I can be sure c < m and can be used as a plaintext RSA2048 input in general.

Comment: For text book RSA every $m \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is valid. For padded RSA see the link that I provided in the first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modulus defines the key length for RSA. So a 2048 bit key has a 1 at the leftmost bit. Otherwise there could be almost any number of zero's following it, each zero becoming less likely, as the modulus value depends on two large random primes - usually in the order of half the bit size of the modulus. So if you want to take a minimum modulus $N$ into account, you can have any 2047 bit message for plaintext RSA - as long as the most significant bit of the most significant byte is zero (commonly RSA uses big endian calculations, so that would be the *highest order bit of the leftmost byte*).

But please note that plaintext RSA is insecure; the security of the scheme would depend on the content of the message. If it by chance is a fully OAEP padded message then it is certainly secure if verified correctly, but I'm not sure you would implement a secure scheme *by chance*. Actually, I would consider it highly unlikely that a scheme would survive even the simplest of plaintext oracle attacks.

Comment: The idea is to generate longest possible ciphertext from password by PBKF2, use Yubikey to decrypt the random-like data, and use another PBKF2 from those "decrypted" data as a key for LUKS disk encryption.

Comment: ...the idea is to protect the LUKS crypto-key by the PIN. This would be a workaround, since I haven't found any way how to store arbitrary data on Yubikey protected by PIN.

Comment: That sounds as properly randomized data. However, I don't see any reason to store more than the output of the hash size. In that case you can still wrap it in a secure scheme such as OAEP. Storing more than the hash size for PBKDF2 actually *could* shift the advantage to an adversary - although if you feed it directly into another KDF I guess that's not *as* likely to happen. Still, outputting more than a single hash doesn't make PBKDF2 any more secure; the hash size is still the limiting factor.