# Does public key encryption support a large message size?

Tags: rsa, public-key

I'm somewhat new to encryption. I see that the actual RSA sizes are 1024 and 2048? Can those key sizes support data blocks of 128 MB?

Comment: Public-key encryption of large data is routinely performed using [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: 1024 is considered too small nowadays, 2048 barely meets requirements as it has a comparable key strength of 112 bits (triple DES instead of AES). RSA works for any key size although only > 512 bit with 8 bit increments are usually supported. One RSA operation always adds padding overhead, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/1172) how much you can encrypt at a time (note the comment below). Besides requiring more computing resources, repeated secure RSA encryption - which *can* be secure - also greatly expands the ciphertext size compared to the plaintext size.

Comment: Note that I think the title and minimal question in the body  is much better than the one of the duplicate. I'll try and keep the question around for that reason - so Google can find it. Guys, please use a minimum of downvotes - finding questions / answers can be tricky.