# Why does symmetric encryption require padding?

Tags: symmetric, padding

Why does symmetric encryption require padding? Is it to avoid the attacker to learn the size of the plaintext?

Comment: I feel like this question is basic enough that it surely *should've* been asked here before, but if it has been, I can't find it. All I found was [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/why-is-padding-used-for-rsa-encryption-given-that-it-is-not-a-block-cipher), which is sort of the exact opposite. Let's see if anyone else can find an earlier duplicate of this question; in the mean time, have a +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symmetric crypto does not always have padding. Stream ciphers often will not require padding. Padding is necessary when using a cipher that requires plaintexts to be a multiple of a particular size. For example, AES in CBC mode requires plaintexts that are a multiple of 128 bits. So if your plaintext is not, you must pad to make it the right size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. so the reason for padding is just the right size? there's no any other reason?(for no other reason?)

Comment: ...that is to say, AES *in CBC mode* requires plaintexts that are a multiple of 128 bits. AES in CTR, CFB, OFB or pretty much any other mode (including most modern AE modes) is fine with any plaintext length. (As for ECB mode, I would argue that it only provides even halfway reasonably security properties for plaintexts that are *exactly* 128 bits long; using it for anything longer leaves you open to trivial attacks.)

Comment: thank you for your comment! According to the your comment, reason for padding is to provide more security?? I understood this. and AES in CTR, CFB, OFB ,or any other mode not need to add the padding??

Comment: @신동평it is not to provide more security, it is to make sure it will decrypt correctly. Without it you encrypt 1 byte in CBC, but get 16 after decryption, which is obviously wrong

Comment: Padding isn't strictly necessary even for CBC mode. It is possible to use ciphertext stealing to deal with plaintext data of bizarre length.