# Pitfalls of manual AES encryption for data transfer

Tags: encryption, aes, key-generation

#### Context

I've used OpenSSL to encrypt some socket communications.
I am however using some functionality from the windows API that prevents me from using OpenSSL's opaque builtin sockets, so I am buffering through their `BIO_s_mem` interfaces - that requires 4 extra copies for all data passing through (`socket->read buffer->read BIO->OpenSSL state machine->write BIO->write buffer->socket`, as opposed to `socket->OpenSSL state machine->socket`).
This is not efficient, especially seen as the goal is (among other things) large file transfers.

#### Idea

As a result I'm thinking I could establish an OpenSSL session, generate some symmetric keys, and use that secure session to share them. I would then open another channel (or just use the underlying socket which I have full control over) to transfer the bulk data using something like AES256-GCM - doing that 'manually' (using OpenSSL crypto libraries) would make it incredibly fast as it would no longer imply the inefficiencies of passing it through the OpenSSL state machine.

#### Problem, Goal & Question

I'm not a cryptographer. I don't even know what I don't know.
All I know is if people can find side-channel attacks based on compression ratio of encrypted data, then any mistakes I make with this would probably be fatal.

I'm aware key generation has to be done very carefully - I've read through [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126988/ways-to-generate-symmetric-and-asymmetric-keys), and I was thinking of using OpenSSL's facilities for the purpose. I'm also aware that AES is by itself secure, but a wrong implementation will easily throw that away.

This does however, on the surface, seem like a manageable challenge.  Generate keys -> Run data through AES256-GCM.  The upside is big, and this is a personal project that likely won't have the most proficient hackers (or any hackers) trying to mess with it. I just want it secure so that if people start to use it, they're not using something could be easily broken.

---

So, is there something obvious I'm missing? Something less than obvious?

Extra considerations, perhaps a correction on something wrong I might have said, some resource I should read before the attempt? All is appreciated, but if your contribution is "just don't do it", I ask you to please add some context as to what could go wrong so I get the picture.

Comment: Why not simply have a look at what TLS is doing here instead of inventing your own and then ask if it is secure? Use something which is proven, don't run your own crypto protocol. Also, I assume that the overhead you envision is not relevant compared to everything else. So better check first that you actually gain relevant performance before trying to implement your own.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm mostly describing what TLS is doing after the handshake, except they generate the keys based on a bunch of information obtained during it. There may be a reason for that I'm not aware of. And while I never really mentioned performance so much as efficiency - I imagine you're right. Even with the AES instructions, networking and kernel calls might take the bulk (until the data rates get high enough anyway, then DMA probably scales in a way manual copies don't). Regardless I felt it could be worth implementing, and generally a good question for future applications as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it secure to use RSA to exchange AES key?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/97790/is-it-secure-to-use-rsa-to-exchange-aes-key)

Comment: @kelalaka mentallurg already linked it in his answer, not my use-case. My use case is using a TLS session to negotiate symmetric keys and then doing the encryption in a separate channel (as opposed to using the TLS session). For the moment it has performance benefits. In the future as I do embedded development, it might become even more useful if I intend on implementing support for hardware crypto units. Doing it in the separate channel wouldn't break or require re-writes when updating openssl (as I wouldn't have to interact with internal APIs). I addressed it in my comments on his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, your approach has following problems that are solved in TLS (see details [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/97998/27923).):

1. It allows man-in-the-middle attacks (TLS doesn't)
2. It allows replay attacks (TLS doesn't)
3. It doesn't provide forward secrecy (TLD does)
4. It doesn't provide key revocation mechanism (TLS does)

Even if one is aware of the these problems and wants to address them in the own solution, a correct implementation of such solutions can require a lot of efforts.

One more potential problem is *key distribution*. Before any communication you need to provide each 2 parties with a key for their communication. In case one of parties lost the key or the device was compromised, you need again to provide these 2 parties with a new key. If the channel to provide the key is not secure enough, an attacker can intercept the key and can then decrypt the communication.

Some people may feel the usage of TLS "boring" or "not cool" compared to implementing their own solutions. But TLS provides solutions for many security risks.

And, as always for security topics, before making a decision, first *evaluate the risks*. What will a successful attack cost you and how much efforts and money are you ready to put to prevent it? For instance, if you want to communicate with a bank and a compromised communication can cost you \$100 000 000, then may be you will put a lot of money and time into implementing highly secured connection. But if you want to communicate with a video camera installed in a forest to observe birds nest, then successful attack on this communication will probably doesn't cost you much and it makes no sense to put let say \$10 000 into security.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer, but you seem to have misinterpreted what I'm suggesting - that was to establish a TLS session beforehand with which to share the symmetric keys between the 2 parties, and then use those to encrypt the flow of information. I think that would mean MITM is no longer possible, replay attacks too because of the use of GCM (a replayed packet should be erroneous because the counter will have changed on the receiver), I would protect against forward secrecy problems by generating a different key everytime, and key revocation would stay a TLS matter.

Comment: @TrisT: In your question there is not single word about TLS. And if you establish a TLS session, then you have everything:

Comment: 1) Encryption is made by TLS - why would you need your own encryption? This will add zero security, but will add only obscurity.

Comment: 2) MITM is prevented by TLS.

Comment: 3) Replay attacks are prevented by TLS, it is based on sequence numbers -  - why would you want to add your additional prevention?

Comment: 4) Forward secrecy is provided by TLS - why would you want to provide your own solution for forward secrecy?

Comment: *In your question there is not single word about TLS* - in my question: "As a result I'm thinking I could establish an OpenSSL session". OpenSSL has deprecated all but TLS1.2 and TLS1.3, so it is implicit that when I say 'OpenSSL session' it will be negotiated as one of those two. As for the other replies, have you read any of my question except for the title? I want to do the same thing TLS is doing but do the symmetric encryption part separately from the OpenSSL session (in a different channel, with the symmetric key being passed through the openssl channel).

Comment: This is useful at the moment for performance reasons (as stated in *Context*), but if I ever want to implement AES512 it will also be appropriate, as well in embedded environments with hardware crypto units that the OpenSSL code does't recognize. In that second case I could program it into openssl and build it, but 1. OpenSSL updates could break my code, requiring more than a simple recompile to update to a newer version (a version that may patch exploits), and 2. if you've looked at the OpenSSL source you'll know doing it in a separate channel sounds like much more painless of a proposition.

Comment: @TrisT: 1) Regarding symmetric encryption: TLS uses symmetric encryption, after session established. I don't understand why you would another implementation.

Comment: 2) When TLS 1.3 was designed, also performance was addressed and 1.3 is faster than 1.2. No one can prohibit you to implement an analog of TLS. Have you measured the performance of TLS? Do you see any issues with that? Is TLS the bottleneck in the entire system? If TLS takes just 1% of ther response time and 99% are application logic, storage, etc, then even if your approach is 1 000 000 faster than TLS, the total performance will change in less than 1%.

Comment: 3) No one can prohibit you to implement anything you want. But if your customers ask security experts to analyze your software before buying it, then I'd suppose the most of them will point out to multiple risks related to your solution. And I'd suppose that the most clients will either ask you to replace this part with TLS or will look up for other solutions.

Comment: You keep replying to me with statements that clearly show you haven't read my question past the title, and don't understand at all what I'm *actually* trying to do. As I said I appreciate your answer but this discussion is pointless because you're arguing against something I'm not even attempting.

Comment: I overlooked that you want to exchange keys using TLS. But other issues remain still relevant. You are saying that your own encryption *"would make it incredibly fast"*. My point 2 above is till relevant. Have you measured what is TLS overhead in the entire response time? 2010 Google switched to use TLS for everything. SSL/TLS overhead was just 1%. Suppose you have the same TLS overhead. Suppose your approach is 2x faster than TLS. Then if you use your solution, your gain will be just 1% / 2 = 0.5%. It means if response time was 1000 ms, it will be 995 ms.

Comment: It's a good point but TLS is a protocol, subject to implementation details. If they made the right implementation it's obviously gonna be very fast, I'm talking about the case where a wasteful implementation is being made. Copying data 4 extra times with the cpu may become a problem if we're talking high data rates. Plus you're talking about google, with the complex services they offer, 1% isn't necessarily a small amount. Google searches often take more than 0.1s. Plus I never mentioned performance, only efficiency, and embedded applications are also relevant but I've already said all this.

Comment: *"Copying data 4 extra times with the cpu may become a problem if we're talking high data rates."* - Why do you think so? Have you measured it? Do simple test - transfer data via TLS and tranfser the same data without any encryption at all. How bit is the difference in your case? 1%? 0.1%? Then decide if this difference is worth optimization.

Comment: Which might have been an appropriate response if I was in the software engineering SE. Given our current situation however, that merely addresses the context of my question, not the question itself which was very clearly about cryptography- hence why I finished it with '*All is appreciated, but if your contribution is "just don't do it", I ask you to please add some context as to what could go wrong so I get the picture.*'. You have good points, none of which help. I provided the current context for the sake of it, but half the reason I posted it was for knowledge gain and future embedded use.

Comment: But this is pointless. I thank you for your answer, and we can leave it at that.

Comment: The purpose of this site is to be helpful not only to a particular user who asked the question, but to be helpful to as any users as possible who may have similar questions.