# In textbook RSA with low public exponent, how big does a random message needs to be?

Tags: rsa, attack

Assume RSA with a public modulus $N$ of $n$ bits, a small odd public exponent $e$, plaintext $M$ a random non-negative integer less than $2^m$ for some integer parameter $m$, with $M\mapsto C=M^e\bmod N$ (textbook RSA) used for encryption. Inasmuch as it matters, assume there are $2^r$ ciphertexts available to the attacker, and her goal is to recover one plaintext with odds better than $2^{-k}$. If necessary also assume $n\ge1024$, $e\le2^{16}+1$, $r\le30$, $k\ge40$, or/and $M$ is of exactly (rather than at least) $m$ bits.

If $M^e<N$, then $M^e\bmod N=M^e$ and thus $M=C^{1/e}$, making decryption trivial by $e^\text{th}$ root extraction. $m\ge n/e+k+r$ makes us safe from trying that for each available ciphertext; but not necessarily against improvements, or other attacks.

**Up to what bound for $m$ do we know an attack better than factoring $N$ using [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve)?**

As an aside: starting with what bound for $m$ (if any) is there a positive security argument?

---

Updates (main question, now highlighted, remains without an answer proposing a bound):

As rightly pointed by [D.W.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/351/d-w)'s in this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8019/555), regardless of $e$, we must also have $m$ big enough to resist being found by "square-root" attack, a "meet-in-the-middle" search using a space/time tradeoff. To be safe from that we can make $m\ge a+b+k$ where the adversary is powerful enough to make $a$ accesses to a memory system of $b$ bits, say $m\ge 90+70+k$.

There is a simple extension to the $e^\text{th}$ root attack: the adversary hopes that an $M$ is divisible by some small integer $s$ of her choice, computes $C'=C\cdot s^{-e}\bmod N=(M/s)^e\bmod N$, then applies the $e^\text{th}$ root attack to $C'$. Perhaps they choose $s$ as the successive primes, or some better method. This considerably extends the range of vulnerable $m$ <sub><sup>(to, uh..)</sup></sub>.

Note: I assume all plaintext is random and independent, and the adversary has no access to a decryption oracle (even limited to revealing messages other than the originals and with at most $m$ bits).

Another simple (and inefficient) extension to the $e^\text{th}$ root attack: the adversary hopes that $k=\lfloor M^e/N\rfloor$ is small enough to be enumerable, and tests if $C+k\cdot N$ is an $e^\text{th}$ root for small $k$. That's independent, but only marginally extends the range of vulnerable $m$, as far as I can tell.

Comment: For a positive security argument, I would think that the best approach is not to pour lots of resources into analyzing textbook (unpadded) RSA, but rather to adopt a padding scheme for which we do have positive security arguments.

Comment: @D.W.: Very right. Of course I do not plan to use textbook RSA for unpadded (even random) messages, I'm asking this question as an extension of [this homework](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/7997/555) (update: which now is deleted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $e$ of moderate size (say $e=17$), Coppersmith's theorem makes it possible to go significantly beyond message size $n/e$.

Take for example a message $M$ of size $m=160$ bits and a modulus of $n=2048$ bits with exponent $e=17$. I can guess the top 40 bits $\textrm{MSB}_{40}(M)$ of $M$, and solve for the remaining 120 bits using Coppersmith applied to the polynomial $f(x) = (A+x)^e - C$ modulo $N$, with $A=2^{120}\cdot \textrm{MSB}_{40}(M)$. $2^{40}$ executions of Coppersmith's algorithm are surely much cheaper than GNFS for 2048 bits, and since this uses little memory, this is also most likely much better than the meet-in-the-middle attack. (I often give this as an exercise to students in the case $m=128$).

Note that this is the correct way of guessing bits in that setting, as opposed to enumerating $\lfloor M^e/N\rfloor$ which is much larger.

This line of attack doesn't help much for larger exponents like $e=65537$, however, and even for $e=17$, I don't know how to push things to message size $m=256$.

Comment: Right and nice. This seems to combine with a technique I suggest (hoping that $M$ is divisible by some small integer $s$ and apply the attack to $C'=C\cdot s^{-e}\bmod N=(M/s)^e\bmod N$ instead of $C$, for various small $s$). I wonder what the best balance is between trying more $s$ and guessing more bits of $M'=M/s$, and how large that makes a recommendable $m$ for say $e=3$.

Comment: It seems to me that hoping $M$ is divisible by some small integer of say $\ell$ bits is essentially equivalent entropy-wise to hoping that the top $\ell$ bits of $M$ are zero, so it basically enters as an additive term in the log-success probability $k$.

Comment: To protect against the approach above, the bound on $m$ should be something like $m\geq n/e+\lambda(n)+k$ where $\lambda(n)$ is the bit complexity of GNFS for bit size $n$ (one could subtract the bit complexity of Coppersmith from that, but I wouldn't: attacking many similar polynomials is actually faster than trivial repetition thanks to tricks like LLL chaining). There is no term for $r$, because it is equivalent (actually a bit faster) to recover more bits of a single message vs. fewer bits of one of several messages. For $e=3$, $n=2048$ and $k=40$, this gives $m\gtrsim 835$.

Answer (score 6):

**Related messages.** If you have (the encryptions of) a pair of messages that differ by a known fixed difference, then the Franklin-Reiter related message attack can be used to recover both messages.  The running time of the attack is something like $O(e^2 n^2)$.  This does not apply if the messages are independent and there are no known relationships between them.

**Coppersmith's theorem.** Coppersmith's theorem might be relevant.  Roughly speaking, it says that if you have a monic polynomial $f(x)$ of degree e, then you can find all solutions to $f(x)=0 \pmod N$ satisfying $0 \le x < X=N^{1/e}$ in polynomial time, using a lattice technique.  By defining $f(x)=x^e-C$, this can be used to recover $M$ if it is known that $M<N^{1/e}$.  Therefore, it looks like this does not improve upon the trivial $e^{\textrm{th}}$ root extraction root method.  I don't know if the attack can be improved by continuing to use his lattice methods even for a larger value of $X$.

**Square-root attack.** There is also a meet-in-the-middle style attack whose running time is $O(2^{m/2})$.  If $e=3$ it will be dominated by other attacks, but it may be more relevant for larger values of $e$.  The meet-in-the-middle attack is described by Boneh et al. (see below); basically, we hope that $M$ can be written as $M=M_1 M_2$ where $M_1,M_2 \le 2^{m/2}$, and we try to find $M_1,M_2$.  To find them, we build a table of $C/M_1^e \bmod N$ for all candidate $M_1$ values, then for each candidate at $M_2$, we look up $M_2^e$ to see if it is present in the table.

This is described in Section 5 of the following paper:

- [Textbook ElGamal and RSA Encryption are Insecure](http://www.di.ens.fr/~pnguyen/pub_BoJoNg00.htm), Dan Boneh, Antoine Joux, Phong Q. Nguyen, ASIACRYPT 2000.

**Published work.** A good summary of the above attacks can be found in this paper:

- [Twenty years of attacks on the RSA cryptosystem](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/RSAattack-survey.html), Dan Boneh, Notices of the AMS, vol 46 no 2, pp.203-213, 1999.

Comment: The "Square-root" attack indeed sets another required minimum for $m$, independent of $e$, and higher than the $n/e+k+r$ minimum for all but very small $e$. I do not see that the other attacks are more effective than the $e^{\operatorname{th}}$-root attack. Note: in the "Coppersmith's theorem" section, was $e$ meant instead of $3$?

Comment: Thanks, @fgrieu, you are completely correct.  I was being a little bit sloppy and thinking primarily of $e=3$. I've edited my answer to apply to general $e$, based upon your comments.  Thanks for the helpful comments!

Comment: And thank you @D.W. for pointing the fully relevant "Square-root" attack.