# Textbook RSA on random numbers mod a smaller prime

Tags: rsa

I have a protocol where I have a random one-time number message $m \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a 256 bit prime from an Elliptic Curve (EDIT:  The order of an elliptic curve prime order group).  I also have a textbook RSA ciphertext $m^e \mod n$, encrypted using a 2048 bit RSA key.  I am using for its homomorphic properties (I can't pad it or the protocol will not work).

Is it safe to use using a message from a large message space that is smaller than the RSA group size?

(EDIT in response to comment):  I am not stuck with any particular value for $e$, but my program does scale with $\log_2{(e)}$, so I would prefer something smaller.

Comment: Here the value of $e$ is important. If $e=3$ a direct cube-root attack is possible. What is the value of $e$?

Comment: I'm not bound to any particular value for $e$, though I would prefer for it to not use too many bits.  $e = 65537$ should be fine, but I can also go larger if that would be safer.

Comment: what's a "prime p from an Elliptic curve?"

Comment: What I meant is the prime order from an elliptic curve.

Comment: The present question seems to be a small variation of [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8017/555).

Comment: My question does not depend on a small exponent.  If a large value of $e$ mitigates an attack, I can use it.