# How to recover RSA messages if they are padded with spaces?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, padding

I have a message `m="hunter"`. Let's say we pad it with 2 spaces from the left making the final message as `m_dash="  hunter"`.

We are given with c where `c=pow(bytes_to_long(m_dash), 3, n)` and n(1024 bit). n is too big to be factorised and therefore we can't get the totient and thus 'd'. And because of that we can't recover our padded-message trivialy by `pow(c,d,n)`. Is there any way I can get my message back?
Original messsage is bigger than 'hunter'. Can't apply cube-root attack.

Comment: [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem, Dan Boneh](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/RSA-survey.pdf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cube-Root attack - RSA with low exponent](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33561/cube-root-attack-rsa-with-low-exponent)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\text{bytes_to_long}(\text{m_dash})^3 < n$