# Help with RSA step

Tags: rsa

There's one thing in RSA that haunts me. In books there's just a statement, that

$$ed \equiv 1 \bmod \varphi(n)$$

is taken from Euler's function somehow. And than we use it to get

$$m^{ed} \equiv m \bmod n$$

I don't understand how we got $ed ≡ 1 \bmod \varphi(n)$. Could we take $ed ≡ 1 \bmod \varphi(n)$ somehow, if we have $m^{ed} ≡ m \bmod n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what I understand the question asks to explain, we can ***NOT*** get $e\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(N)}$ from $m\equiv m^{e\,d}\pmod n$, even if we add that the later congruence holds for all $m$.

Proof by counterexample: $p=11$, $q=17$, $n=p\,q=187$, $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)=160$, $e=3$, $d=17$, $e\,d=81\not\equiv1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$. Yet $\forall m,\, m\equiv m^{e\,d}\pmod n$ (which can be verified exhaustively for integers $m$ from $0$ to $n-1$, and also follows fact 2 below).

---

Two related facts hold if $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes and $n=p\,q$ :

1. $e\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)}\implies\forall m,\, m\equiv m^{e\,d}\pmod n$
2. $e\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\lambda(n)}\iff\forall m,\, m\equiv m^{e\,d}\pmod n$

where $\varphi$ is the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), and $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). They verify $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ and $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$. The later divides the former.

The left-to-right implication in facts 1 and 2 is proven in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1006/555). 
The right-to-left implication in fact 2 follows from a definition of $\lambda(n)$ as the smallest positive exponent $k$ such that $\forall m,\, m^k\equiv1\pmod n$. The first part of the present answer shows that equivalence does not hold in fact 1.

---

The reasons why it is often used $e\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$ in RSA are that

- $\varphi(n)$ is, by definition, the order of the group $\mathbb Z_n^*$ (that is, the number of elements in the set of integers $m$ with $0<m<n$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$). It follows that $\forall m\in\mathbb Z_n^*,\, m^{\varphi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$, and from that
  $e\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)}\implies\forall m\text{ with }\gcd(m,n)=1,\, m\equiv m^{e\,d}\pmod n$
  which is a simple proof of a large subset of fact 1 above, and one that works for all $n$ (there's not need to invoke that $n$ is the product of distinct primes).
- RSA was first described this way and with this proof in R.L. Rivest, A. Shamir, and L. Adleman's [*A Method for Obtaining Digital Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystem*](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf).
- Using $\varphi(n)$ works perfectly fine in practice (that follows from fact 1), and avoids the slightly more complex calculation of $\lambda(n)$.
- For most choices of $p$ and $q$ following standard recommendations, using $\lambda(n)$ typically only leads to a slightly lower $d$, and a slight speedup in some implementations of the RSA private-key operation; and then not even always, and speed-optimized implementations turn out not to use $d$ at all anyway.
- Since $d$ is secret, using $\varphi(n)$ or $\lambda(n)$ causes no incompatibility issue at least as long as the private part of the key is not shared among several devices.

Comment: I think this answer is only likely to add to the OP's confusion.

Comment: @TonyK: The answer being accepted comforts me that I did not add to confusion. In too many RSA expositions, the condition $e\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$ falls out from nowhere; it is legitimate and sound to question that abuse of authority and ask: A) if that condition can be derived from $m^{ed}\equiv m\bmod n$ (the answer is no, first part of answer). B) if the reverse hold (yes, fact 1). C) if a similar, mathematically more satisfying relation could be derived (yes, fact 2). D) why the teacher and many implementations use $e\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$ (third part).

Comment: @Tonyk: and from the [OP's next question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48186/555), my attempt at guessing what the OP wanted (stated in the first paragraph of my answer) might have been right.

Answer (score 2):

> how did we get $ed \equiv 1 \bmod \phi(n)$?

For ["textbook RSA"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa), you choose secret primes $p$ and $q$, and from them, derive $N =pq$ and compute $\phi(N) = \phi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1)$. Now you *choose* $e$ such that $\gcd(e, \phi(N)) = 1$. Then you publish $(N,e)$ as your public exponent.

Once you have $e$, you use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to compute the modular inverse $d \equiv e^{-1} \bmod \phi(N)$, or $ed \equiv 1 \bmod \phi(N)$.

If you select $e$ and $d$ this way, then the solution to $m^e = c \bmod N$ is $m = c^d \bmod N$.

The attacker will have access to $N$ and $e$, but they won't know $\phi(N) = (p-1)(q-1)$ because they don't know $p$ and $q$. This is because factoring $N$ into $pq$ is [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity).

Another way of saying it: if the attacker doesn't know $\phi(N) = (p-1)(q-1) = N - (p+q) + 1$, then it's no easier for her to find out $\phi(N)$ than it is to figure out the secret primes $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Just a small hint: `\bmod` tends to be shorter than `\text{ mod }`. `\pmod{m}` will also add parenthesis around the modulus.

Comment: You also may want to use `\greek-letter-name` like `\phi` or `\Phi` or `\varphi` ($\phi,\Phi,\varphi$) and `\equiv` ($\equiv$).