# Trying to understand the basic principle of RSA from Wikipedia

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

Quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation

> A basic principle behind RSA is the observation that it is practical
> to find three very large positive integers $e$, $d$, and $n$, such
> that with modular exponentiation for all integers $m$ (with $0 ≤ m < n$)
>
> $$ (m^e)^d \equiv m \pmod{n} $$
>
> and that knowing $e$ and $n$, or even $m$, it can be extremely
> difficult to find $d$. The triple bar ($\equiv$) here denotes modular
> congruence (which is to say that when you divide $(m^e)^d$ by $n$ and
> $m$ by $n$, they both have the same remainder).

1. What does $(m^e)^d$ mean? is it $m^e\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}d$ or is it $m^{e\times d}\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}n$ or something else?
2. If $0 ≤ m < n$ then $m$ *mod* $n = m$. If so what's the point of writing it as $ (m^e)^d \equiv m \pmod{n} $ instead of just $ (m^e)^d\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}n= m$

With question 1 I think I have a basic understanding that modular exponentiation is calculating modulus on the result of exponentiation, but I think I'm confused about the notation.

With question 2 I think I might be misunderstanding something because otherwise using modular congruence doesn't make sense.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.se The first one is really a basic power of a number knowledge that $(m^e)^d = m^{ed}$. For the second, $\equiv \pmod n$ is equivalence relation and $=$ the remainder. We have dupe for the second. We suggest you a basic algebra course/book on your learning path. Also see [RSA: in $E(x) \equiv x^e \pmod N$, do we apply the mod function to $x^e$?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/107839/18298) Here it is in more detail. For 1) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Positive_exponents

Comment: $m^e \cdot m^d = m^{e+d}$ and $(m^e)^d \bmod n = m^{ed} \bmod n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $(m^e)^d\equiv m\pmod n$, as long as $e$ and $d$ are positive integers, the fragment $(m^e)^d$ means $m$ raised to the power $e$, then raised to the power $d$, that is
$$\underbrace{{(\,\underbrace{m\times\ldots\times m}_{e\text{ terms}}\,)}\times\ldots\times{(\,\underbrace{m\times\ldots\times m}_{e\text{ terms}}\,)}}_{d\text{ terms}}$$
and (by associativity of multiplication) that's equal to $m^{(e\times d)}$.

The notation $u\equiv v\pmod n$ means $u-v$ is some multiple of $n$, but does not specify a range for either $u$ or $v$. Therefore, $(m^e)^d\equiv m\pmod n$ means that *if* we evaluated $\left(\left(m^e\right)^d\right)-m$ we'd obtain some multiple of $n$.

In contrast, the notation $u=v\bmod n$ or equivalently $v\bmod n=u$ mean $0\le u<n$ and $u\equiv v\pmod n$ (as defined above), thus uniquely specifies the integer $u$ as a function of $v$ and $n$.

Therefore, $(m^e)^d\equiv m\pmod n$ conveys less information than does $(m^e)^d\bmod n=m$, because only the second states that $0\le m<n$.

If we know $0\le m<n$ (e.g. because that's an enforced restriction), then $(m^e)^d\equiv m\pmod n$ and $(m^e)^d\bmod n=m$ are equivalent.

In the computation of ciphertext $c$ from $m$, $e$, $n$ in textbook RSA, we want to write $c=m^e\bmod n$ which fully specifies $c$, not $c\equiv m^e\pmod n$ which allows several $c$, including $c=m^e$ which makes it trivial to find $m$ from $c$, $e$, $n$.

In order to actually compute $c$ with $c=m^e\bmod n$ from $m$, $e$, $n$ we can limit to integers less than $n^2$ and perform at most $2\log_2e$ multiplication steps. E.g. for $e=17=2^4+1$, we'd need only $5$ multiplications followed by Euclidean division by $n$ keeping the remainder, by computing:
$$\begin{align}
m_2&\gets(m\times m)\bmod n\\
m_4&\gets(m_2\times m_2)\bmod n\\
m_8&\gets(m_4\times m_4)\bmod n\\
m_{16}&\gets(m_8\times m_8)\bmod n\\
c&\gets(m_{16}\times m)\bmod n\\
\end{align}$$